# Bugzilla installation error: Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference

Tags: bugzilla

While installing bugzilla,I have got the error message like

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 2083
```

Could anyone please help me out? Below is my cmd prompt(windows 7) running screenshot preview

```
Reading ./localconfig...

OPTIONAL NOTE: If you want to be able to use the 'difference between two
patches' feature of Bugzilla (which requires the PatchReader Perl module
as well), you should install patchutils from:

    http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.00)     ok: found v4.022
Checking for                MySQL (v4.1.2)    ok: found v5.1.59-community

WARNING: You need to set the max_allowed_packet parameter in your MySQL
configuration to at least 3276750. Currently it is set to 1048576.
You can set this parameter in the [mysqld] section of your MySQL
configuration file.

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
Checking for             GraphViz (any)       ok
Migrating old chart data into database...
TestProduct:
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line
2083.

C:\Bugzilla>
```

Comment: *"WARNING: You need to set the max_allowed_packet parameter in your MySQL
configuration to at least 3276750. Currently it is set to 1048576.
You can set this parameter in the [mysqld] section of your MySQL
configuration file."* - I would give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the contents of c:\Bugzilla\data\mining - for some reason on Windows it has a problem overwriting those files.